# Impala SQL group_contact() increments by month

Tags: sql, impala, group-concat

I have a data set which contains information on several individuals by month, such as:

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 201901 |
| 1 | 201902 |
| 2 | 202004 |
| 3 | 202101 |
| 3 | 202102 |
| 3 | 202103 |

I want to create a new variable that includes all months over which the individual as appeared on the dataset but increasing with the month, like this:

| id | date | months |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 201901 | 201901 |
| 1 | 201902 | 201901,201902 |
| 2 | 202004 | 202004 |
| 3 | 202101 | 202101 |
| 3 | 202102 | 202101,202102 |
| 3 | 202103 | 202101,202102,202103 |

I was trying to use SQL's group_concat() function but this will give me a row with only all dates for each individual.

```
select id,
group_concat(DISTINCT cast(date as string)) AS months 
from ...
group by id
```

Is there any way for me to achieve what I want in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

SQL isn't the right tool for this, but it can be done. I think you should add row numbers per id and do a STRING_AGG in a subquery where you also do row numbers per id over all rows with a row number greather than or equal to the row number of your outer query.

Comment: Could you be more specific on the subquery part? With some example code maybe? Thanks a lot!